# Deep coping c++ - To Make a copy of a class if pointer to that class is given

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

I am new to copy constructor concept .I have a basic question.
Wanted to implement a function like

```
orig *f1(orig*o)
{
  // Returns a copy of *0 and should deep copy all the values of the parent
  // pointer.Planning to implement a copy constructor to achieve the same.
  // Can anyone provide a prototype or some idea on the same?
}
class dummyclass
{
 int value;
};
class orig
{
  dummyclass *dummy;
  char str[100];
public:
 //default constructor
:
//parametrised constructor
 orig(char *p)
{
   dummy = new dummyclass;
  //rest of the initialisation
}
orig(const orig& duplicate)
{
//copy constructor
}
};
int main()
{
  orig o("Hello");//constructor
  orig dup(o);//copy constructor
   }
```

I know in this way we can invoke copy constructor.But if pointer to o ie *o is given how to invoke copy constructor and do a deep copy.

Comment: When wanted you can invoke the copy constructor as per Mark Garcia's answer. You can create a constructor from the pointer - it should do what the copy constructor should also do - `dummy = new dummyclass(p->dummy); std::copy(str, p->str, p->str + 100);`. You'll need a destructor to `delete dummy`.  Having a `clone()` function on `dummyclass` is a more structured approach, but overkill for one `int` member.

Comment: @TonyD In fact using a pointer at all is already *overkill* here.

Answer (score 2):

Then dereference `o`:

```
orig* o = new orig("Hello");
orig dup(*o);
```

Comment: so basically i can do this orig *f1(orig*o) { orig dup(*o); return *dup; }..Also if we have a copy constructor is it needed to overload assignment operator?

Comment: You can do it but you *should* have its return value a dynamically allocated variable (otherwise it just returns a pointer to a non-existent object).

Comment: You mean inside the copy constructor i should do dup = new orig and copy each value?

Comment: No. I mean in the function `f1`, you should do it like this: `orig* dup = new orig(*o); return dup;`

Comment: Ok.If i have a class which is having pointer which is dynamically created and owned by some other class is it necessary that the copy has to be deep?